# Android eclipse Error: adb connection lost. server error

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred.

You must restart adb and Eclipse.

Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/ASDK/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed

WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Answer (score 0):

this question was raised by me and here I am explaining my experience.

Actually this question was raised when one of my friend was trying to setup android on his laptop but his micromax mobile could not be detected for debugging. he is just a teen eager. I suggested above answer and some other solutions to him one of which is installing mobomarket mobile synchronization software (used for micromax mobiles- a company whose adb driver can not be installed  automatically).

He install that s/w but facing this error every now and then. one thing he observed that this s/w installed req adb driver for micromax mobile. but port no 8700 on which adb process used to run was occupied by this new s/w.

so he made very good assumption that if he uninstalled the s/w driver will not be uninstalled. and trick works. good thing is that he completed his whole android app without facing this error.

hope this trick will help you all.